# Add legend to ggplot with dataframes added through a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to add a legend to this plot and can't figure it out! I have set up the plot to loop through multiple dataframes based on the "csv_files" list and add a geom_line to the plot, but can't figure out how to add a legend that shows the color of each line and the corresponding dataframe. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
ggplot() +
  # Loop through each dataframe to add a line
  lapply(seq_along(csv_files), function(i) {
    df_name <- paste0("h", gsub(".csv", "", csv_files[i]))
    df <- get(df_name)
    
    geom_line(data = df, aes(x = DateTime, y = depth), color = i)
  }) +
  labs(title = "Hobo Data",
       x = "",
       y = "Depth") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have color within `aes()` as aesthetic, in order to have it as legend, the next code visualizes randomly generated data:

```
csv_files <- paste0(1:5, rep('.csv', 5)) # generate data for 5 csv files

get <- function(n=500) { # 500 data points for the timeseries
  data.frame(DateTime=Sys.Date() + sort(sample(1:(n+1), n)),
                   depth = runif(n)) 
}

ggplot() +
  # Loop through each dataframe to add a line
  lapply(seq_along(csv_files), function(i) {
    df_name <- paste0("h", gsub(".csv", "", csv_files[i]))
    df <- get()
    geom_line(data = df, aes(x = DateTime, y = depth, color = as.factor(i)))
  }) +
  labs(title = "Hobo Data",
       x = "",
       y = "Depth",
       color="color") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]